# How do I display CommercialVehicleFlag which can be in different xpaths?

Tags: xml, xslt

**New information:** 
After modifying my xsl as follows, 
**modified xsl code.**

```
<nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
<xsl:for-each select="//Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]">
    <xsl:value-of select="CommercialVehicleFlag"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am getting 2 CommercialVehicleFlag together which is wrong.

Current wrong output.

```
<nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>falsefalse</nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
```

Desired output.

```
<nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>false</nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
```

I am trying to display **CommercialVehicleFlag** from xml document. 
My xsl is working on one xml document but not on the other. This is because the **CommercialVehicleFlag** can be either under **Charge** or under **Citation** in xml document. However it cannot be in both nodes in the same xml document. 
The sample xml I have pasted here shows **CommercialVehicleFlag** from two different xml documents. 
One under **Charge** and the other one under **Citation**.
My xsl is only working for **VehicleLicensePlateNumber** in this xpath `/Integration/Case/Charge/Vehicle/VehicleLicensePlateNumber` and failing for this xpath `/Integration/Citation/Vehicle/CommercialVehicleFlag`.

In my xsl I need to check for both paths. How do I do this?

**xml document with CommercialVehicleFlag under Charge**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67084884" xmlns="">
    <Case Op="E" InternalID="1617090736" ID="12125870" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <CaseNumber>55</CaseNumber>
        <Charge ID="10906336" PartyID="16770378" InternalChargeID="1616713996" InternalPartyID="1614673416" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
            <ChargeOffenseDate>05/28/2015</ChargeOffenseDate>
            <Vehicle>
                <VehicleLicensePlateState>MM</VehicleLicensePlateState>
                <VehicleLicensePlateNumber>ASD123</VehicleLicensePlateNumber>
                <VehicleMake Word="JEEP">Jeep</VehicleMake>
                <CommercialVehicleFlag>false</CommercialVehicleFlag>
                <HazardousVehicleFlag>false</HazardousVehicleFlag>
            </Vehicle>
        </Charge>
    </Case>
</Integration>
```

**xml document with CommercialVehicleFlag under Citation**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67086833" xmlns="">
    <Citation ID="5380737" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <CitationNumber>33</CitationNumber>
        <TicketDate>12/25/2014</TicketDate>
        <Vehicle>
            <CommercialVehicleFlag>false</CommercialVehicleFlag>
            <HazardousVehicleFlag>false</HazardousVehicleFlag>
        </Vehicle>
    </Citation>
</Integration>
```

My xsl code which is only displaying CommercialVehicleFlag under Charge and not under Citation

```
<!--Template for ext:Charge-->
    <xsl:template name="Charge">
        <ext:Charge>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(count(ChargeHistory[@Stage='Disposition Event']))>0">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ChargeHistory[@Stage='Disposition Event']">
                        <xsl:sort select="@DispositionEventSequence" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <xsl:call-template name="ChargeDetails"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ChargeHistory[@Stage='Case Filing']">
                        <xsl:sort select="@FilingSequence" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <xsl:call-template name="ChargeDetails"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </ext:Charge>
    </xsl:template>



    <!--Charge Details Template-->
<xsl:template name="ChargeDetails">
    <j:ChargeSequenceID>
        <xsl:value-of select="ChargeNumber"/>
    </j:ChargeSequenceID>
    <j:ChargeStatute>
        <j:StatuteDescriptionText>
            <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode"/>
        </j:StatuteDescriptionText>
        <j:StatuteText>
            <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode/@Word"/>
        </j:StatuteText>
    </j:ChargeStatute>
    <j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
        <xsl:value-of select="Statute/Degree"/>
    </j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
        <ext:Citation>
            <nc:ActivityDate>
                <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Citation/CitationCharge[ChargeID=current()/../@ID]">
                    <nc:Date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(../TicketDate))"/>
                    </nc:Date>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </nc:ActivityDate>
            <nc:Identification>
                <nc:IdentificationID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Citation/CitationNumber"/>
                </nc:IdentificationID>
                <nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
                    <nc:JurisdictionText>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Citation/Agency/@Word"/>
                    </nc:JurisdictionText>
                </nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
            </nc:Identification>
        </ext:Citation>
        <ext:Vehicle>
            <nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Citation/Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]">
                <xsl:for-each select="//Case/Charge/Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]">
                <xsl:value-of select="../Vehicle/CommercialVehicleFlag"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
        </ext:Vehicle>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT? In particular can you show how the named template `ChargeDetails` get shown, as the answer will very much depend on which element you are positioned on when you call the template. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSLT currently uses a nested `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Citation/Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Case/Charge/Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]">
```

But this will never return anything in your case. If `CommercialVehicleFlag` is under `Charge` then the first `xsl:for-each` will not select any nodes, and so the second `xsl:for-each` will not apply.

On the other hand, if the first `xsl:for-each` does select something, then according to your logic, `CommercialVehicleFlag` won't be under `Charge` and so the second `xsl:for-each` won't return anything.

What you can do, is use the union operator `|` to combine the two expressions into one. If `CommercialVehicleFlag` can indeed only occur in one place, this will return the relevant node.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Citation/Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]|//Case/Charge/Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]">
```

Note that, if you only have one `Vehicle` node in your XML, you could actually simplify it to this instead

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]/CommercialVehicleFlag"/>
```

Then it wouldn't matter when it appeared. It would select it wherever it occurred in the XML.

EDIT: If you have multiple `Charge` elements in your XML, it looks like you only want want the one relative to the node you are positioned on, so you could try something like this:

```
<nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
   <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Citation/Vehicle[CommercialVehicleFlag]|../Vehicle/CommercialVehicleFlag"/>
</nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
```

Or maybe just this will do...

```
<nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
   <xsl:value-of select="../Vehicle/CommercialVehicleFlag"/>
</nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
```

Comment: Tim the `Vehicle` can appear more than once in a xml document. For example in `Charge` I have added a sample of xml document with Vehicle appearing twice.

Comment: Tim the `Vehicle` can appear more than once in a xml document. For example in `Charge` I have added a sample of xml document with Vehicle appearing twice. When I modified my xsl code per your suggestion, I am getting this output `<nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>falsefalse</nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>` This is wrong. I just want to have one false like this: `<nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>false</nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>`

Comment: I've expanded my answer with some suggestions.